# How to send a mail via Activesync from an android app?

Tags: android, email, activesync

we have an application that need to interact with mail.
For that, our customer want us to : 
- Retrieve the Activesync parameters the user have entered on the general parameters of the phone.
- Send the mail in a silent way using these activesync parameters.
- Be able to read and parse a possible reply to the mail on the Exchange server.

I  know that it may cause severe security issue (retrieve a private password from an application is not a good practice..), but i can't find any clue on the sdk to communicate and send mail via activesync.

If anyone have some informations, i would be glad to hear about it.

Thanks a lot

Antoine